# Akka, dropping earlier messages

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to drop earlier messages from an actor. The base idea is to have a timestamp on each message, store it for the last processed message message and drop messages earlier than this timestamp.

I am thinking to create mailbox for that, however I don't know:

1. If it is a good idea to keep a state in a mailbox.
2. How I can share the state of the actor (that has the timestamp) with the mailbox.

Maybe I am trying to something wrong and there is a better alternative for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it more?
Do you mean every message will have timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean every message will have a timestamp?
 
 - Then you can have a lastProcessed var in actor and check every message against it and then decide whether to process or not and update lastProcessed var


The message does not have a timestamp and whenever an actor receives it, it attaches timestamp?

In that case, every message will be received and processed in order and I don't know how timestamp plays a role in this case. Can you explain it more what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom mailbox for that is overkill. You can solve it like this:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  val timestampLimit: LocalDateTime = ???

  def receive = {
    case m: Message if (m.getTimeStamp.isBefore(timestampLimit)) => // drop
    case m: Message                                              => // process
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first idea then I though that hiding that behind a Mailbox would be a good idea. But I am less and less convinced by this idea. My second approacj is to compose the receivers so that the "filtering logic" is still partially hidden in the "main" receiver.